# google calculator results for android

Tags: android, google-chrome, calculator

I am making an android application which requires to send a mathematical question like 1+1 to google's calculator and I need to get that result which is displayed on the web. How can I achieve this on android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to create a URL for the equation you are trying to calculate and then use a URLConnection to open the URL and read the webpage source code to find the answer to the equation.

For example if you have the equation:

**2+2**

Then the URL to calculate the result with the Google Chrome calculator would be:
https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=2%2B2

You will have to construct the proper query in the URL for the equation you are solving.  In this URL the query at the end has the equation 2+2:

**q=2%2B2 *(where the %2B represents the + sign)***

After constructing the URL open it with a URLConnection and read the source.  The answer to the equation will be in this element:

```
<span class="cwcot" id="cwos">4</span>
```

So you can parse the source in order to find that particular span element and retrieve the result of your equation.

This is probably more work than you expected but it is the only solution I can think of to accomplish what you asked.  Also, this approach may be error prone and may break easily. I would consider using a different approach altogether such as launching an intent to use the calculator app on the mobile device (even though this approach has issues as well).

**EDIT:**

This worked for me (it will output: 2 + 2 = 4):

```
public static void test() {
    try {
        String source = getUrlSource();
        String span = "<span class=\"nobr\"><h2 class=\"r\" style=\"display:inline;font-size:138%\">";

        int length = span.length();         
        int index = source.indexOf(span) + length;

        String equation = source.substring(index, source.indexOf("<", index));

        System.out.println( "equation: " + equation);           
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static String getUrlSource() throws IOException {
    String url = "https://www.google.com/search";

    String charset = "UTF-8";
    String param1 = "2+2";

    String query = String.format("?q=%s", URLEncoder.encode(param1, charset));

    HttpsURLConnection urlConn = (HttpsURLConnection)new URL(url + query).openConnection();

    urlConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
    urlConn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        a.append(inputLine);
    in.close();

    return a.toString();
}
```

Comment: I thank you for the time you spared to answer, I did just as you said for the first part. Okay, I have this link for my equation: "https://www.google.com.tr/#q=2%2B2" for 2+2. My main problem is I couldn't find a way to parse that element. I mean I parse the page as json and search for "cwos" inside that json but I am unable to find it. How am I supposed to get to that element for the answer? Thanks again and sadly I kind of have to connect to the google calculator

Comment: this is the closest I could get, but sadly one does not receive the result of the mathematical question in the read URLConnection.

Comment: @SuhrahjRothgar I could find that element when I opened the url in a browser but it is not in the webpage source code from URLConnection.  You may be able to find the following: <span class="nobr"><h2 class="r" style="display:inline;font-size:138%">2 + 2 = 4</h2></span> The "nobr" seems to unique so you can search for that in order to get the result of the equation.  Also you may want to check out Google's Custom Search API but I have never used it. https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview